# PHP If statement showing up blank in mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Since i changed Database connection my if statement has not been working in one of my Results.

Here is the code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc)) {
if ( $row['blood'] == "1") echo '<img class="thumbnail" src="./img/blood.bmp" alt="Blood"     height="106" width="213"> ';
    }
```

I have checked all the obvious issues, the table is there, the connection is working on all other results and on my row the "blood" value is 1

Here is the query:

```
 $resultc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dogtags WHERE steamid32 = '".$steamid."'");
```

I am sorry if this is a stupid question i haven't run into this problem before...

Edit:
http://gyazo.com/af5917b8164940f12f8d798732764701
Blood Does = 1

Comment: Try with `$row['blood'] === "1"` or `$row['blood'] === 1`

Comment: @Aleksandar His code should still work if `blood` is 1 or "1". http://codepad.org/79z3YQx3

Comment: I know, but, the difference is in triple equals comparasion. To check that is the same type and value. I had the same issue once and that was solution, so I am suggesting to try that.

Comment: There's no need to inspect variables by indirect methods, we are not detecting exoplanets. Just `var_dump()` it!

Comment: since you changed your database connection, maybe your `mysqli` got different standard settings now. try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc, MYSQLI_ASSOC))` to be sure your `mysqli` is set to associative mode.

Comment: Dump your row result `var_dump($row);`.

Comment: None of these methods does anything... Literally nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `empty()` function which check if anything is there and you can use `isset()` to check wheather the field is set.It checks for `checks for a null (boolean==false) on the field`.

```
if ( empty( $row['blood'] == 1)) {
//handle the code
}
```

Comment: Why should we filter boolean expressions with `empty()`? I can't see any obvious benefit and the code becomes more unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `var_dump($row["blood"]);`? Are you sure it's a String? Maybe try `if($row["blood"] == 1)`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a string or an integer. PHP will convert the variable if necessary. But it does make a performance difference.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Not enough to warrant a change, however. You're unlikely to notice much of a difference, especially if you're using a bytecode cache (which you should be on a production server).

Comment: It only makes a noticeable difference if you're doing that thousands of times.